# Are the following regular expressions equivalent?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

Is $$ 0((01+0)^+(0+10)1) = ((0+01)^+(01+101))^+1?$$

I think it's not , because the language generated by the regular expression on the left accepts the word 00101, but the language on the right doesn't accept it.
Am I right?

Comment: What's the ${}^+$ operation? Is it the same as the Kleene star?

Comment: @Gae.S. It's the Kleene plus operation, similar to the star operation but the expression in parentheses needs to appear at least once, or any number of times more than one.

Comment: It seems to me that you are correct, but the systematic way of determining whether two regular expressions accept the same language is a bit complicated. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961632/how-should-one-proceed-to-prove-or-find-if-two-regular-expressions-are-same-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. In fact, all words described by the expression on the right hand side end with `11`; on the other hand, all words described by the expression on the left hand side end with `01`. Thus the languages described are even disjoint.